# TCP Sockets in React Native?

Tags: sockets, react-native, tcp

I'm trying to use `react-native-tcp` with React-Native 50 and I'm getting `"Native module cannot be null"`.

https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp/issues/55

Is anyone using this successfully that can lend a hand?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: I did. I started using https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started using https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp and it works great. You'll have to have to detach in order to use it and be sure to read the installation notes.

Comment: I tried using it, but it gave me random errors.  Did you successfully install it?

Comment: Yeah. Did you do the things in the Additional Dependencies section?

Comment: You have to patch streams.

Comment: I'm trying it with Ignite boilerplate but I really need websocket protocol, any clue?

Comment: @ßãlãjî you can use const socket = net.connect(PORT, IP, () => {  });